# Selected sub items in a tree-shaped checkbox list

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

I have a viewmodel in javascript that includes checkbox items.

**Javascript is here:**

```
var data = [
    {"name": "Computers", 
       "subcategories":[{"name":"Mac"}, {"name":"Desktop"}]}, 
    {"name": "Mobile Phones" , 
       "subcategories":[{"name":"Nokia"}, {"name":"Sony"}, {"name":"iPhone"}]}
];

var viewModel = {
    categories: ko.observableArray(data),
    selectedCategories: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**HTML code is like this:**

```
<p>Categories: </p>
<div data-bind="foreach: categories">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedCategories, checkedValue: $data.subcategories"/> <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: subcategories">
            <li><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedCategories, checkedValue: $data"/> <label data-bind="text: name"></label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Selected items: </p>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedCategories)"></div>
```

[image]

When I click the main checkbox of a category (**Computers**) subcategories(**Mac, Desktop**) didn't populated. So I should clik again **Mac** and **Desktop** checkbox, but duplicated records inserting in selecteditems.

Here is [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/3HQyG/) code.

Comment: Please include code in your question as well, so the question isn't susceptible to link rot.

Comment: That fiddle doesn't look like the code or UI you supplied in your question. Ah-ha, you updated your fiddle without changing the link: http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/3HQyG/1/

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is the `checkedValue` binding in the parent category is storing the whole `subcategories` array as an array of objects when checked, when what I believe you want to happen is to store each object in the `subcategories` array individually. One way to accomplish that is with a `click` handler instead of `checked` and `checkedValue`.

**JavaScript:**

```
var data = [
    {
        "name": "Computers", 
        "subcategories": [{"name":"Mac"}, {"name":"Desktop"}]
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Mobile Phones" , 
        "subcategories": [{"name": "Nokia"}, {"name": "Sony"}, {"name": "iPhone"}]
    }
];

var viewModel = {
    categories: ko.observableArray(data),
    selectedCategories: ko.observableArray(),
    toggleCategory: function(category, event) {
        var checked = event.target.checked;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(category.subcategories, function(item) {
            viewModel.selectedCategories.remove(item);
            if(checked) {
                viewModel.selectedCategories.push(item);
            }
        });
        return true;
    },
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Categories: </p>
<div data-bind="foreach: categories">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: $root.toggleCategory"/> <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: subcategories">
            <li><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedCategories, checkedValue: $data"/> <label data-bind="text: name"></label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Selected items: </p>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedCategories)"></div>
```

Notice the new `toggleCategory` method on the view model and the `click: $root.toggleCategory` binding that replaced the old `checked` and `checkedValue` bindings are the only pieces that have been changed.

Working JS Fiddle (tested in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/L2eWg/1/